How to change home url in Orange HRM instance from default to custom page
I have installed custom instance of Orange HRM by using docker and want to change home url when banner pressed at right top corner from default (orangehrm.com) to my organization's official page. But coudn't find location of that source code inside the container. Can someone tell exact location of that source code or any other ways to do that?
I get inside the container via docker exec -it "container_id" and tried to find that source code, but no result. I tried to find it in /var/www/html/ location.
